# How to add a request parameter to ajax Request for jQuery dataTable initialized from jSON and mapped by Spring

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, json, spring

I have a jQuery dataTable initialized from jSON and mapped by  Spring

Currently, I do not pass any parameter and retrieve all information, but I need to pass one String to the Java method, probably through a request parameter.

What is best method of doing this?

The front-end code:

```
table = $("#retrievedTable").dataTable({
    "bServerSide" : true,
    "sAjaxSource" : "/cm/credit/getretrievedTable.json",
    "bProcessing" : true,
    "sPaginationType" : "full_numbers",
    "bRetrieve" : true,
    "bDestroy" : true,
    "bAutoWidth": false,
    "bLengthChange": false,
    "iDisplayLength": 20,
    "aoColumnDefs": [{
        "mRender": function ( data, type, row ) {
            return moment(data).format("MM/DD/YYYY");
        },
        "aTargets": [ 0 ]
    }]
});
```

The server-side code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getretrievedTable.json")
public void getTable(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp, Model model) throws IOException
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/server_side/custom_vars.html

fnServerParams

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "scripts/server_processing.php",
        "fnServerParams": function ( aoData ) {
            aoData.push( { "name": "more_data", "value": "my_value" } );
        }
    } );
} );
```